# Firebase push notifcation not working on single device ios but works for user segment

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, capacitor

I am using firebase for push notifications and developing a mobile app using ionic/capacitor. I register the push notifications and get back a token like this...

```
PushNotifications.requestPermission().then( result => {
  if (result.granted) {
    PushNotifications.register();
  }
});

PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
  (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
    alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
    console.log(token.value);
  }
);
```

In the firebase console I can successfully send and receive notifications when targeting my app in the user segment but when I try to target a single device by copying and pasting in the token using send test message I do not receive the push notification. Note: this works fine for me on Android.

Token looks like this...
BAAEF129E8F596F1305D0FEA2F50E21B2768FEFCA83CF19602CA0183077E441D

Comment: How does your token look like?

Comment: BAAEF129E8F596F1305D0FEA2F50E21B2768FEFCA83CF19602CA0183077E441D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capacitor uses APNS for push, that token you got is a APNS token and those don't work on FCM.
Not sure how did you integrate FCM into Capacitor, but you should convert the APNS token to FCM token.

It's something like this

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(CAPNotifications.DidFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError.name()), object: error)
            } else if let result = result {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(CAPNotifications.DidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken.name()), object: result.token)
            }
        }
    }
```

For more information you can check [this guide](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase) about how to integrate FCM into Capacitor.

Comment: I registered an APNs key, downloaded the certificate and uploaded to firebase. My understanding is that Firebase should be able to relay push notifications for iOS devices to APNs but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: FCM send the notifications to APNS, but you have to use FCM tokens, not APNS tokens, you need that code I provided to do the APNS to FCM token conversion.

Comment: You're right. I got it working now. I used a third party plugin though https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm